# Get post data in controller using ajax form submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am submitting this form using ajax and i want all form post data in controller to submit form in database.But its not working.

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
   $.ajax({
     url : controllerUrl, 
     type : 'POST',
     data : $(this).serialize(),
     success : function(data) {

     }
   });
});
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting all post data in controller when i print_r that post data

Comment: try to print $_POST without any index. Or else try posting without ajax to check if php memory limit is causing any issue.

Comment: do you have variable contolllerUrl? looks like typo

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 0):

**Hope it helps you :**

*use `site_url` or `base_url` instead of `controllerUrl`*

**Note** : *replace `controller_name` and `method_name` with your controller and method*

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
     $.ajax({
         url : "<?php echo site_url('controller_name/method_name');?>", 
         type : 'POST',
         data : $(this).serialize(),
         success : function(data) {
             alert(data);
         }
     });
});
```

Your controller structure should be like this :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Controller_name extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construtct()
    {
       parent::__construtct();
       $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function method_name()
    {
       print_r($this->input->post());
       die;
    }
}
```

Comment: are u still not getting the post data

Answer (score 0):

Better try to give it a name for the value you are passing to the next page

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
     $.ajax({
         url : controllerurl, 
         type : 'POST',
         data : {values:$(this).serialize()},
         success : function(data) {
             alert(data);
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: i m not getting post data in controller but form post data display in browser url

Answer (score 0):

```
var your_data = "your data";
var url = "<?php echo base_url('my_controller/my_method') ?>";

$.post( url, { data: your_data}, function(response) {
alert(response);
});
```

for my_controller

```
public function my_method() {
   $data = $this->input->post('data');
   echo 'Found: ' . $data;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is your form

```
<form name="form1" id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="t1">
    <input type="text" name="t2">
    <input type="submit" name="sbtn" id="sbtn">
</form>
```

Put this in your footer

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var BASE_URL ="<?= base_url(); ?>";
    $( "#form1" ).submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: BASE_URL + "controller/methodName",
            data: =$("#form1").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And finally put this in your controller

```
function methodName()
{
    echo $t1=$this->input->post('t1');
    echo $t2=$this->input->post('t2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is your form

**html**

```
<form name="form" id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <a class="adddata">send</a>
</form>
```

AddCategories is controller name and addProductsCategories is method
name.

**js**

```
$(".adddata").on('click',function(){
var addCat= new FormData($("#form1")[0]);

$.ajax({

    url : baseurl+"AddCategories/addProductsCategories",
    type :"POST",
    data :addCat,   
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    success:function(res)
    {
        alert("Good job!");
        window.location.reload();
    }
  });
});
```

**controller**

```
public function addProductsCategories()
{
   $result=array
    (
      "name"=>$_POST["name"],
      "email"=>$_POST["email"],
    );

   $this->db->insert("tbl_name",$result);
}
```